# Sending HTML table data to a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the table in the below format.

```
FirstName Last Name 
Jill      Smith 
Eve       Jackson
```

Also i have Form for updating the firstname & lastname. This is the form code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form border="1">
  <tr>
     <td><label >FirtsName</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="firstname" class="medium"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label >LastName</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="lastname" class="medium"></td>
   </tr>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

How to send the table data to a form using jquery or javascript. Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks & regards
Karthick

Comment: I see no form code in your example.  Where is this form?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ Brad: Sorry, Now i have changed to form. How to get the table data to a form using jquery or java script. pls help me.

Comment: @OscarJara : I am trying to get the HTML table data to a form. I want to display the html table row to a form

Comment: @Leeish: Any idea on this

Comment: Can you not use PHP or ASP for this? Does it need to be js/jquery? What sort of DB is it? MySQL?

Comment: @Bobster4300 No i am not using PHP or ASP also no database is used here. Only a static HTML table is used. from that we have to get the table data & show it in form

Comment: So you have two html pages, and you want to submit data from one page to another using only jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in js, but you could submit the form each time the input looses the focus

Use `<form name="myform" border="1">`

and :

`<input type="text" id="firstname" class="medium" onBlur="document.forms["myform"].submit()">`

there's probably better ways to do this but here's just an idea...

**-- Edit : --**

sorry i forgot something important : you have to name your form like this :

```
<form name="myform" action="file.php">
```

Comment: when you say table data you mean input data which are in the table?
you cant only get data from <input> and <textarea> tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good in english, so maybe I don't understand well enough, but to do what you want, I would do like this :

First things first, you should improve your HTML code, this will make the job a lot easier :

In your users table :

- `<table> </table>`: add an `id` to handle it more easly with jQuery : `$('#id')` method

ex: `<table id="users"></table>`

- `<thead><tr><th> </th></tr></thead><tbody> </tbody>`: use this markups allow you to distinguish table header from table content
- `<tr> </tr>`: add an `id` on the server side to know who is who (i.e : if you have two John Smith)

ex: `<tr id="name_01"><td>...</td></tr>`

- `<td> </td>`: add a `class` attribute to know where is the firstname and the last name

ex: `<td class="firstname">...</td><td class="lastname"></td>`

In your form :

- `<form> </form>`: add an `id` to grab it more easly too

ex: `<form id="usersform"></form>`

- `<table> </table>` : don't forget the `<table>` markup !
- `<label> </label>`: add the `for` attribute matching the input id

ex: `<label for="firstname" >FirtsName</label>`

Now, your table should look like this :

```
 <table id="users">
      <thead>
           <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th><th>Last Name</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
           <tr id="name_01">
                <td class="firstname">Jill</td><td class="lastname">Smith</td>
           </tr>
           <tr id="name_02">
                <td class="firstname">Eve</td><td class="lastname">Jackson</td>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

There are several ways for make what you want, but, basically, there is two main ways :

1. Have only one of the table entry in the form at a time
2. Have all of the table entries

#### I - Only one table entry at a time

HTML

```
 <form id="usersform" name="usersedit" >
      <table id="users">
          <tr>
              <td><label for="firstname" >FirtsName</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" id="firstname" class="medium"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><label for="lastname" >LastName</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" id="lastname" class="medium"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
 </form>
```

jQuery :

```
//When there is a click on a line of the table
$('#users tbody tr').click(function(e) {
    //Get the <tr> id
    userid = $(this).attr('id');
    //Put the value of the firstname cell in the firstname input
    $('#usersform input#firstname').val($(this).find('td.firstname').html());
    
    //You can add a name attribute or an id for later works
    $('#usersform input#firstname').attr('name','first'+userid);
    
    //Now for the lastname input
    $('#usersform input#lastname').val($(this).find('td.lastname').html()).attr('name','first'+userid);
}
```

#### II - All table entries

HTML

```
 <form id="usersform" name="usersedit" >
      <table id="users">
           <thead>
                <tr>
                     <th>Firstname</th><th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           </tbody>
      </table>
 </form>
```

jQuery :

```
//When there is a click on the table (#users) :
$.('#users').click(function(e){
    //handle the part of the form where we want to add input field
    myformtable = $('#userform table tbody');
    
    //For each row in the table
    $.('#users tbody tr').each(function(e) {
        //Create and append a new line
        userline = $(document.createElement('tr'));
        userline.appendTo(myformtable);

        //Create and append a firstname cell
        tdfirstname = $(document.createElement('td')).addClass('firstname');
        tdfirstname.appendTo(userline);

        //Create and append a firstname input
        firstname = $(document.createElement('input')).addClass('medium');
        firstname.appendTo(tdfirstname);

        //Add attribute
        firstname.attr({type: 'text', name: 'first'+$(this).attr('id')});

        //Set value
        firstname.val($(this).find('.firstname').html());

        //Same things with the lastname
        tdlastname = $(document.createElement('td')).addClass('lastname');
        tdfirstname.after(tdlastname);

        lastname = $(document.createElement('input')).addClass('medium');
        lastname.appendTo(tdlastname);

        lastname.attr({type: 'text', name: 'last'+$(this).attr('id')});

        lastname.val($(this).find('.lastname').html());
    }
}
```

You can improve it with a loop, or use css pseudo-class to handle your table cells or form inputs, but I thought it was easier to understand this way.